# Number of unlabeled hypergraphs (A003180)

Tags: oeis, hypergraphs

I'm looking for the number of unlabeled hypergraphs on n nodes and stumbled upon the comments of [A003180](https://oeis.org/A003180) in OEIS. Can somebody please explain to me how that sequence relates to the number of unlabeled hypergraphs?

For example, I think there should be 6 unlabeled hypergraphs on 2 nodes, the edge set could consist of:

- nothing
- 1 node
- 2 nodes
- nothing + 1 edge ("edge" meaning edge containing all two nodes)
- 1 node + 1 edge
- 2 nodes + 1 edge

But the sequence claims it should be 4.

Comment: The offset for sequence A003180 is zero, so it actually states there are $4$ unlabeled hypergraphs on $1$ node, and $12$ on $2$ nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your enumeration is correct for [OEIS sequence A000612](https://oesi.org/A000612) where hypergraphs have hyperedges of non-empty subsets. The [Wikipedia article Hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) states

> There are variant definitions; sometimes edges must not be empty, and sometimes multiple edges, with the same set of nodes, are allowed.

The comment in A003180 assumes that empty hyperedges are allowed so `A003180(n) = 2*A00612(n)`. I have added an extra comment to clarify this issue. Note that the OFFSET of A003180 is $0$ so `A003180(2) = 12` is the number of hypergraphs with empty hyperedges allowed also.

Thanks for your question.